# How do I find out who the Account Executive (AE) is for an Org?

Tags: account-management

Given an arbitrary production org, how can I find out who the Salesforce Account Executive (AE) is and what their contact details are?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The details are exposed via the Checkout that is accessible via the App Selector just before the AppExchange option.

[image]

If you can't access the Checkout ensure that your profile has either the **Manage Billing** permission or the **Checkout Enabled** permission. See [What is Checkout & how can I access it?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187504&language=en_US)

This will take you to https://store.salesforce.com/home where the AE details appear on the bottom right of the page. The Send Mail button is the mailto: link for their email address.

[image]

**Updated UI:**

[image]

See Also:

- [Who is my Salesforce Account Executive (AE)?](https://www.shellblack.com/administration/who-is-my-salesforce-account-executive-ae/)